# PHP code not getting MySQL table values

Tags: php, html, mysql

I've seen quite a bit of questions like this one, but none have really helped me out. I'm trying to write a bit of code that fetches values from a MySQL table and prints them out. Whenever I try to run the code, it either doesn't run it and just shows the raw code, or it returns a MySQL error. My PHP is as follows:

```
 <?php
 $servername = "localhost";
 $username = "root";
 $password = "toughtohackpassword";
 $dbname = "weirddb";

$con = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);


$sql = "SELECT * FROM `class1`";


$result = mysql_query($sql, $con);


if (!$result) {
    echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}


$data = "";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $data .= "<tr>
                <td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>
                <td>" . $row['score'] . "</td>


              </tr>";
 }

exit;

 ?>
```

By the way, the error message is `Could not successfully run query (SELECT * FROM class1 from DB:'.

I know this question is very general, so please tell me if I need to add anything!

Comment: Why the heck are you mixing `mysqli_connect` and then `mysql_` functions? Of course this is not going to work.

Comment: (facepalm) Right. I'm quite new at PHP, could you tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Make sure to not use `mysql_` but `mysqli_`...

Comment: @developerwjk Would that mean I would have to replace every instance "mysql" with "mysqli"?

Comment: @JavaThunderMan Try to search for `mysqli_*`. There are many documents and procedures that you will definitely understand how to use.

Comment: @JavaThunderMan Absolutely, you need to do that.  But also, go to google and look up each function, and refer to the docs on php.net for that function, to see if the order or the parameters is the same or not, so google "mysqli_fetch_assoc" etc.

Comment: Do you mind posting the fixed code?

Answer (score 0):

```
$con = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
            ^----mysql **I**

$result = mysql_query($sql, $con);
               ^---mysql **WITHOUT** I
```

If you have even absolutely bare bones minimal error handling on your code, instead of blindly assuming that nothing could ever go wrong, you'd have been told that your query failed because there's no connection to the database:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql, $con) or die(mysql_error());
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Do you mind posting the fixed code? Thanks.

Comment: you can't change `mysql` to `mysqli` in your own code? IF you're too busy to hit the `i` key a few times, you're too busy to be on this site...

Comment: Wasn't sure there...Excuse me.

Answer (score 0):

Basically it looks like you are mixing mysql with mysqli

```
    <?php
 $servername = "localhost";
 $username = "root";
 $password = "toughtohackpassword";
 $dbname = "weirddb";

$con = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);


$sql = "SELECT * FROM `class1`";


$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));



$data = "";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $data .= "<tr>
                <td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>
                <td>" . $row['score'] . "</td>


              </tr>";
 }

exit();

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 $servername = "localhost";
 $username = "root";
 $password = "toughtohackpassword";
 $dbname = "weirddb";

$con = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);


$sql = "SELECT * FROM `class1`";


$result = mysqli_query($sql, $con);


if (!$result) {
    echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " .     mysql_error();
   exit;
   }


$data = "";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $data .= "<tr>
               <td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>
              <td>" . $row['score'] . "</td>


             </tr>";
 }

exit;

 ?>
```

You use MySQLi for connect to database so you must use "MySQLi" instead of "MySQL" in function

Answer (score 0):

Hi Java Thunder Man,

```
<?php
     $servername = "localhost";
     $username = "root";
     $password = "toughtohackpassword";
     $dbname = "weirddb";

     $con = mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
     //---Make sure those variables for connecting DB are correct
     //And please using one DB connection method (PDO/mysql/mysqli so on)

     $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `class1`") or die(mysql_error());

     $data = "<html>";
     $data .= "<body>";
         $data .= "<table>";
         if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0) {//list the result if rows of $sql > 0
              while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
                   $data .= "<tr>";
                   $data .= "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
                   $data .= "<td>" . $row['score'] . "</td>";
                   $data .= "</tr>";
              }
         }
         $data .= "</table>";
     $data .= "</body>";
     $data .= "</html>";
     echo $data; //Show the results by using echo

 ?>
```

I am also new in PHP and I am not sure the error appeared i which line except you didn't echo $data.
Furthermore, can you state the error more clear? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Run this, it should work for you if you have no typos in your table and column names you are trying to query.

```
<?php
 $servername = "localhost";
 $username = "root";
 $password = "toughtohackpassword";
 $dbname = "weirddb";

$con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM class1";

$result = $con->query($sql);

if ($con->error) {

    die("Could not connect to database");

} else {

    $data = "";

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        $data .= "<tr>
                    <td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>
                    <td>" . $row['score'] . "</td>
                  </tr>";

     }

    echo $data;
    exit;
}

 ?>
```